# source code of "query selection" from a TFS widget

Tags: tfs

Every TFS default widget provided by Microsoft allows to select title, size and a query. I'd like to develop a custom widget but I didn't find the source code for the selection of a query (as show in image). Is there any example of source code in github or elsewhere? [image: query selection field]